# Why is Taiwan is having a string of COVID-19 cases now?

Tags: covid-19

Taiwan started having COVID-19 cases since May 2021 peaking at 7.5 K and going down now but severe enough that the China mainland stopping vaccine supply was a big deal. What changed from their previous highly successful strategy?

https://www.cdc.gov.tw/